# I am trying to install PySimpleGUI package. But i am getting Fatal error in Launcher

Tags: python-3.10

I am getting below error when i try to install PySimpleGUI. I tried tying pip instsall PySimpleGUI in Terminal of Pycharm.
Also, i tried to download PySimpleGUI- 4.6 ...tar.gz and kept in the scripts and lib . Still same issuefaced.
Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\mthamilm\Desktop\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\mthamilm\PycharmProjects\charmpr\venv\Scripts\pip.exe" install PySimpleGUI': The system cannot find the file specified.

Please help to resolve it.

Comment: Please use code blocks. Also, as stated in the error message; the system can't find the file. File, in this question, is `pip`.

Comment: Install a library on PyCharm is different from on the console window. Try to google about `pycharm install library`.